# Can I remove apt source for somerville-three-eyed-raven on XPS13 after upgrade to Jammy?

Tags: apt, dell, 22.04, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 that originally came with Ubuntu 18.04. I believe that I reinstalled 20.04 on it from scratch. At that point `/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta.list` contained:

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
```

In May 2020 an `apt upgrade` installed oem-somerville-meta and upgraded oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven from 20.04ubuntu3 to 20.04ubuntu4 resulting in `/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta.list` containing:

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
```

The upgrade to 22.04 resulted in the file containing:

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville-three-eyed-raven
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
```

as might be expected.

However, now every time I run `apt update` I get:

```
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'somerville-three-eyed-raven/binary-amd64/Packages', as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-three-eyed-raven' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'somerville-three-eyed-raven/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-three-eyed-raven' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'somerville-three-eyed-raven/i18n/Translation-en', as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-three-eyed-raven' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'somerville-three-eyed-raven/i18n/Translation-en_GB', as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-three-eyed-raven' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'somerville-three-eyed-raven/dep11/Components-amd64.yml', as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-three-eyed-raven' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'somerville-three-eyed-raven/cnf/Commands-amd64', as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-three-eyed-raven' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Can I safely just remove the `somerville-three-eyed-raven` lines from `/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta.list`, or should I be using a different repository?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue for `somerville-squirtle` component. Dell Latitude 7420 here. May be this needs to be asked on Dell forums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that it's safe to uninstall `oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta` after the upgrade. This will uninstall various other packages, but none of them should be required since the standard 22.04 packages include support for all the hardware. The long justification for this follows.

I did some digging into what I had installed from that repository and what those packages contained. Firstly:

```
$ dpkg -l 'oem*'|grep '^i'
ii  oem-somerville-meta                  22.04ubuntu2 all          hardware support for Somerville project
ii  oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta 20.04ubuntu4 all          hardware support for Somerville Three-Eyed-Raven platform
```

It appears that I originally had `oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta` installed for Focal, it gained a dependency on `oem-somerville-meta` in May 2020, so that got installed at that point.

The `oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta` package contains `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta.list` with contents

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
```

The upgrade to 22.04 changed the file in my filesystem to contain:

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
#deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ jammy somerville-three-eyed-raven
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-three-eyed-raven
```

and of course there's no `http://dell.archive.canonical.com/dists/jammy-somerville-three-eyed-raven/` directory.

The `oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta_20.04ubuntu4_all.deb` package contains:

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./etc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./etc/apt/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./etc/apt/sources.list.d/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       270 2020-05-12 09:41 ./etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta.list
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2020-05-12 09:41 ./usr/share/doc/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       455 2020-05-12 09:41 ./usr/share/doc/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta/changelog.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1037 2020-05-12 09:41 ./usr/share/doc/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta/copyright
```

The `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta.list` file is the only one with any real effect.

The `oem-somerville-meta_22.04ubuntu2_all.deb` file contains:

```
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-04-26 13:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/doc/oem-somerville-meta/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       245 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/doc/oem-somerville-meta/changelog.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1012 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/doc/oem-somerville-meta/copyright
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/glib-2.0/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       326 2022-04-26 13:01 ./usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/15_oem-somerville-meta.gschema.override
```

and the only file there with any effect is `15_oem-somerville-meta.gschema.override` which contains:

```
[org.gnome.shell]
favorite-apps = ['ubuntu-desktop-installer_ubuntu-desktop-installer.desktop', 'ubiquity.desktop', 'firefox_firefox.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'rhythmbox.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop', 'yelp.desktop']
```

which (I assume) populates the initial set of favourite applications for Gnome shell.

So, for anyone that doesn't care about that initial set of favourite applications (which is probably almost everyone) the only benefit of having these packages installed is their dependencies. For `oem-somerville-meta` these are `dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend, ubuntu-oem-keyring` and for `oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta` these are `ubuntu-oem-keyring, linux-generic-hwe-20.04, oem-somerville-meta`. That dependency on `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` in turn means a dependency on `linux-generic-hwe-22.04`. (There isn't currently a newer hardware-enablement kernel available for 22.04.)

I think this means that it's safe to uninstall `oem-somerville-meta`, `oem-somerville-three-eyed-raven-meta`. Doing this means that `apt autoremove` will also remove `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`, `linux-generic-hwe-22.04`, `linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04`, `linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04` and `ubuntu-oem-keyring`. Removing all of those packages hasn't caused me any problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand correctly, the somerville are patches for the hardware and it will be added to future LTS versions.

You can go to http://dell.archive.canonical.com/, search for Jammy-somerville-*. I didn´t found mine (somerville-pidgeot).

I had the same problem. With this clues and with no other answer, i had disabled it. You can disable with '#' before every line. You can enable deleting these Hashtag. You will need superuser permission, for example:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-somerville-pidgeot-meta.list
```

or your favourite Texteditor instead of Vim.

You are not going to broke anything, that is yet not broken. These are the repository for an old version. I have no problem at the moment. My hardware works fine and i have no more the Error message.

For Reference:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/oem-priority/+bug/1920196